# MySQL: Order by with joins and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following tables:

**message_notification**

```
 ________________________
| id | message   | user  |
|____|___________|_______|
|  1 |     10    |   1   |
|____|___________|_______|
|  2 |     11    |   1   |
|____|___________|_______|
|  3 |     12    |   1   |
|____|___________|_______|
```

**message**

```
 _________________________________________
| id |    post   |         date           |
|____|___________|________________________|
| 10 |     10    |   15-11-2015 19:45:36  |
|____|___________|________________________|
| 11 |     20    |   15-11-2015 19:47:44  |
|____|___________|________________________|
| 12 |     10    |   15-11-2015 19:53:12  |  
|____|___________|________________________|
```

**post**

```
 ________________
| id |  content  |
|____|___________|
| 10 |     XX    |
|____|___________|
| 20 |     XX    |
|____|___________|
```

I would like to get notifications **grouped by** post and **ordered by** posts with the newest messages.

So, I would like to get following results:

```
1. post #10    
2. post #20
```

and if someone write new message in post #20, results will be following:

```
1. post #20   
2. post #10
```

I have tried following query, but seems like order by doesn't work with group by or inner joins

```
SELECT noti.*
FROM message_notification noti
INNER JOIN message mess ON mess.id = noti.message
INNER JOIN post ON post.id = mess.post
WHERE noti.user = 1
GROUP BY post.id
ORDER BY mess.date DESC
```

Comment: Why not just ORDER BY post.id, post.date without grouping?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Your sample results specify posts.  Yet, your sample query returns columns from a table that has no column for the post.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using any function. ORDER BY post and date its enought.
Remember all columns in SELECT clause have to be in GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

First you should filter out the later date(maximum date) from `message` for each
post. 
Please try this out.

```
SELECT noti.*
FROM message_notification noti
INNER JOIN (SELECT message.* 
           FROM message
           INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT id,MAX(`date`) AS dater 
           FROM message 
           GROUP BY id) T ON T.`dater` = message.`date`) mess ON mess.id = noti.message
INNER JOIN post ON post.id = mess.post
WHERE noti.user = 1
GROUP BY post.id
ORDER BY mess.date DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` to only select the most recent message per post

```
select * from post p
join message m on m.post = p.id
join message_notification mn on mn.message = m.id
where mn.user = 1
and not exists (
    select 1 from message m2
    join message_notification mn2 on mn2.message = m2.id        
    where m2.post = m.post
    and mn2.user = 1
    and m2.date > m.date
)
order by m.date desc
```